# 'Weaker' feedback reduces DC Gain?

Tags: operational-amplifier, feedback, stability

### **My Understanding**

From my previous understanding of stability and op-amps, I know that placing an op-amp in a closed-loop configuration reduces the DC gain and extends the 3-dB bandwidth as seen in the image below:

[image]

1. The DC gain has reduced from $$A_{OL} \rightarrow \frac{A_{OL}}{{1+\beta A_{OL}}}$$
2. The 3dB point and hence the single dominant pole has moved to $$\omega _{p0} \rightarrow \omega _{p0}(1+\beta A_{OL})$$ where beta is the feedback factor. Thus, we get a bandwidth extension.

### **What the book says**

[image]

In Chapter 10 of Razavi's book, he has the explanation above.

### **My Concerns**

**Q1:**
*He says that if we decrease the feedback factor beta, the gain decreases (see the grey line in the figure). But as per my understanding (see drawn figure), decreasing the feedback factor should increase gain (the gain should get closer to open-loop). What am I misunderstanding?*

**Q2:**
*In Fig 10.7, even with a decreased feedback factor (grey line), the poles remain at the same location as they did with the higher feedback factor (black line). How? Why are we no longer benefiting from bandwidth extension as my understanding?*

Also, I understand he's dealing with a multipole system rather than a dominant pole in my drawn figure but that shouldn't make a difference to my questions (I think).

Apologies for the long question. I had a really long thought about this but the book kept going against my understanding, so I had to post here.

Comment: But fig 10.7 is showing a loop gain **LG = Aol x beta**, and not the closed-loop gain **Acl = Aol/(1 + beta x Aol)**  did you notice that?

Comment: @G36 Ahh! That makes complete sense now! Thank you so much. I don't know why I just assumed the graph to be closed loop gain.

Comment: I'm glad that I could help http://educypedia.karadimov.info/library/acqt0131.pdf